How to limit selenium memory consumption in celery?
I am running several FireFox browsers (with help of python selenium) in celery tasks and saving results into PostgresDB. Each celery-task is a separate process
My server configuration
CPU - 20 cores
RAM - 32 GB

My application infrastructure configuration:
services:
  django:
    command: sh -c "
      sleep 3 && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core_app.wsgi"
      # not important

  db:
    # not important

  celery:
    image: harbor.mgns-tech.ru/content-protect/main-app:dev
    command: celery -A core_app worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=19
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
    # environment variables declared in the environment section override env_file
      - DEBUG=1
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=65535

This configuration works fine for 30 new celery tasks per hour, but for 50 tasks I see the following picture. No available memory(RAM) at 9:30am :

After 9:30am I can't connect to the server via ssh (have to restart server) and don't see successful celery tasks
How to control/limit max memory consumption in celery?
I think that I close selenium properly - in destruction of browser class I have following:
    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        try:
            self.driver.quit()
            logger.info("Selenium driver closed")
        except:
            pass
        
        try:
            self.display.stop()
            logger.info("Display stopped")
        except:
            pass

